# Looking for a particular class of functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I would like to characterize functions $f: [0, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$ that satisfy $$ f(z) \geq f(x) + f(y)  $$
for all $x,y < z$ with $x +y \geq z$. I am also interested in examples. Moreover, I was wondering whether there exist functions $g: [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ that satisfy the condition from above.

Comment: I can provide some necessary conditions. $i)$ $f$ is discontinuous everywhere on $[0,\infty)$. $ii)$ $f$ is injective on $[0,\infty)$. It's easy to get these necessary conditions by arguing by contradiction.

Comment: @SamWong Thanks. I also started to think that most of such functions are defined on $\mathbb{N}_0$. Because then $\exp$ already works and in fact any function $f(x)= k^x$ with $k \geq 2$.

Comment: Yeah, but your domain is discrete. I am afraid that $f$ can not exist and I am trying to work on the proof of the non-existence of the function $g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Claim: There doesn't exist a function $g:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ which satisfies the condition in the problem.**

As my comment mentions, any such function $g$ must be discontinuous everywhere on $[0,1].$ We will prove that every such function $g$ is of bounded variation. And we know every function of bounded variation can be expressed as a difference of two non-decreasing functions, and by the Lebesgue' theorem, we know every function of bounded variation is differentiable almost everywhere, and hence continuous almost everywhere, which contradicts to my comment above.

Now let $g:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ be a function which satisfies the condition in the problem.

Let $P=\{x_0,x_1,...,x_n\}$ be a partition of $[0,1]$ with $x_0 =0$ and $x_n=1$.

So, $$V(g,P)=\sum_{i=1}^n |g(x_i)-g(x_{i-1})|\le\sum_{i=1}^n |g(x_i)|+|g(x_{i-1})|.$$

For $i\in\{ 1,2,...,n-1\}$, there always exists some $z_i$ in $[0,1]$ s.t. $x_{i-1},x_i<z_i,$ and $x_i+x_{i-1}\ge z_i.$ Indeed, we can take $z_i$ as any real number approaching $x_i$ from the right(i.e. slightly greater than $x_i$).

Note that $g$ is non-negative.

Now we have that, $$ V(g,P) \le |g(x_n)|+|g(x_{n-1})|+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} |g(x_i)|+|g(x_{i-1})|\le |g(x_n)|+|g(x_{n-1})| +\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} g(z_i).$$

Denote $x_{n-1}$ by $z_n.$

Then we get, $$V(g,P) \le |g(x_n)| +\sum_{i=1}^{n} g(z_i).$$

Note that, we can bound $g(z_i)+g(z_{i+1})$ with $g(h_i)$ for some $h_i\in[0,1]$ with the similar trick above.

Repeating this process, we get less and less terms on the R.H.S. And eventually, we get only two terms on the R.H.S, which are $g(x_n)$ and $g(m)$ for some $m\in[0,1].$

We get, $$V(g,P)\le 2$$ because $|g|$ is bounded by $1$.

Since the partition $P$ is arbitrary, we conclude that the total variation of $g$ is bounded by $2$, which implies that $g$ is of bounded variation.